# CsvHelper Configuration.ShouldQuote - return true for only fields on the DTO which are strings

Tags: c#, nuget, csvhelper

Hi have a DTO object with a number of properties with different types, `string`, `int` or `bool` etc.

I would like to apply double quotes around the `string` properties only.

In the `Configuration.ShouldQuote` the `field` parameter values have all been converted to `string` so there is no way of knowing whether the original type from the DTO was a `string`, `int` or `bool`.

Is there a way I can find the underlying property type from the DTO so that I can pass back `true` from `Configuration.ShouldQuote` only for fields that were originally of type `string`?

```
public class TestDTO
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public bool Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

```
    var rawData = new[]
    {
        new TestDTO { Field1 = "Field1", Field2 = 1, Field3 = true },
        new TestDTO { Field1 = "Field2", Field2 = 10, Field3 = false }
    };
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
    {
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) =>
            {
                return field is string; // doesn't work as all fields at this point are strings
            };

            csv.WriteRecords(rawData);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want that? A CSV file is a *text* file. All fields are text as far as the CSV format is concerned. Quotes say nothing about the contents. A CSV file in a non-US culture could use `,` as the field separator and handle commas as a *decimal* separator by quoting all decimal fields, eg `"3,14"`. Another file could quote *all* fields

Comment: Are you trying to force Excel to treat some fields as if they were text and some as integers? In that case it would be better to create a real Excel file with eg Epplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) =>
{
    var index = context.Record.Count;
    var type = ((PropertyInfo)context.WriterConfiguration.Maps.Find<TestDTO>().MemberMaps[index].Data.Member).PropertyType;
    if (type == typeof(string))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return ConfigurationFunctions.ShouldQuote(field, context);
};
```

You can also use a custom converter.

```cs
public class QuoteStringConverter : StringConverter
{
    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var innerQuotes = ((string)value).Replace(row.Configuration.QuoteString, row.Configuration.DoubleQuoteString);
        var quotedValue = row.Configuration.Quote + innerQuotes + row.Configuration.Quote;
        return base.ConvertToString(quotedValue, row, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

Turn quotes off and add your converter to the `TypeConverterCache`

```cs
var rawData = new[]
{
    new TestDTO { Field1 = "Field1", Field2 = 1, Field3 = true },
    new TestDTO { Field1 = "Field2", Field2 = 10, Field3 = false }
};

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
{
    csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => false;
    csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<string>(new QuoteStringConverter());

    csv.WriteRecords(rawData);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

CsvHelper has changed the `ShouldQuote` behavior several times, and [Version 23](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/migration/v23/) changed this behavior once again from one with a multi-argument delegate to one with a single parameter of type `ShouldQuoteArgs`.

A really simple example that quotes all non-empty strings:

```
    ...
    var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        ShouldQuote = args =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Field)) return false;

            return args.FieldType == typeof(string);
        }
    };
```

The default `ShouldQuote` handler in the CsvHelper source is a good place to look for more ways to handle quoting.